# Univariate vs Multivariate LMER psuedo r-squares

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, multivariate-analysis, r-squared

I have a multivariate (three DV's) repeated measures (Three time points) linear mixed effects model that I ran. As apart of the model diagnostic I'm attempting to calculate the psuedo r-squared value through r2glmm::r2beta.

As a result, I see an r-squared value of nearly 97%, which is unheard of in this area of study.

I then ran three separate univariate repeated measures linear mixed effect models.

Each model shows r-square values of less than .1%

The models are as follows:

Multivariate:

```
model <- lmer(value ~ variable:Time -1 + (0 + Time | Group_ID/Participant_ID))
```

Univariates:

```
model <- lmer(DV1 ~ 1 + Time + (1 + Time | Group_ID/Participant_ID))
model <- lmer(DV2 ~ 1 + Time + (1 + Time | Group_ID/Participant_ID))
model <- lmer(DV3 ~ 1 + Time + (1 + Time | Group_ID/Participant_ID))
```

Is there a sensible reason as to why this discrepency between r-square values is happening?